# Formalize the proof of theorem 2.4 in Harper's PFPL

Tags: programming-languages, induction

In Harper's [Practical Foundations for Programming Languages](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Erwh/pfpl/2nded.pdf), page 19, rule (2.9) defines the $sum$ function inductively.

$$
\frac{b:nat}{sum(zero;b;b)}\tag{rule 2.9a}
$$

$$
\frac{sum(a;b;c)}{sum(succ(a);b;succ(c))}\tag{rule 2.9b}
$$

Then the author introduced Theorem 2.4 to prove $sum$ is indeed a function, that is, $c:nat$ is guaranteed to exist and to be unique for any $a:nat$ and $b:nat$.

The proof of existence does a rule induction on $a:nat$. This is essentially a mathematical induction on a single variable. I think I understand the proof and can translate it into a formal one without much difficulty.

But the proof of uniqueness frustrates me a lot.

First, the author decides to do the induction on rule 2.9 (rather than 2.2). My understanding is that here we can have a set-theoretic view of the function $sum$. It could be thought of as a relation $\Sigma$, a subset of $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$. Each element $r \in \Sigma$ is a 3-tuple $\langle a,b,c\rangle$ where $a,b,c \in \mathbb{N}$. The set $\Sigma$ is inductively defined by rule 2.9. From this viewpoint, a structural induction on $\Sigma$ is perfectly acceptable (as a newbie I spent substantial amount of time to figure this out).

The author states the property to be held as "if $sum(a;b;c_1)$, then if $sum(a;b;c_2)$, then $c_1\;is\;c_2$", which could be straightforwardly translated into

$$
sum(a;b;c_1) \rightarrow (sum(a;b;c_2) \rightarrow c_1\;is\;c_2)\tag{a}
$$

But I am not sure whether it is a single variable predicate $\mathcal{P}(sum(a;b;c_1))$, or a two-variable one $\mathcal{P}(sum(a;b;c_1),sum(a;b;c_2))$. Since "an inner induction" is mentioned in both parts (2.9a and 2.9b), it seems the latter is in author's mind, but I have no idea how a two-variable induction works.

In the induction step (rule 2.9b) the author seems to put the induction hypothesis as

$$
sum(a^\prime;b;c_1^\prime) \rightarrow (sum(a^\prime;b;c_2^\prime) \rightarrow c_1^\prime\;is\;c_2^\prime)\tag{b}
$$

then the goal is to prove something like

$$
sum(a;b;c_1) \rightarrow (sum(a;b;c_2) \rightarrow c_1\;is\;c_2)\tag{c}
$$

where $a,c_1,c_2$ are successors of their primed version respectively.

I understood the statement "We have that $a\;is\;succ(a^\prime)$ and $c_1\;is\;succ(c_1^\prime)$, where $sum(a^\prime;b;c_1^\prime)$." as

$$
sum(a^\prime;b;c_1^\prime) \rightarrow sum(a;b;c_1) \tag{d}
$$

and "we may show that if $sum(a;b;c_2)$, then $c_2\;is\;succ(c_2^\prime)$ where $sum(a^\prime;b;c_2^\prime)$" as

$$
sum(a^\prime;b;c_2^\prime) \rightarrow sum(a;b;c_2) \tag{e}
$$

Even each piece looks reasonable, I failed to combine those pieces into a whole picture. I expect from induction hypothesis (b), with rules 2.9, natural deduction rules of first order logic, $\mathcal{P}(conclusion)$ (c) should be arrived. But I cannot figure out how.
I get stuck here.

The author's proof is intuitively correct. But I do hope to see:

1. a formal proof, or an explanation or clarification from where a formal proof can easily be constructed.
2. confirmations or corrections of the descriptions and predicates above.
3. if this is a two-variable induction, how it works (in the context of rule induction)?

Comment: Can you please add the definition of the `sum` function and the rule in the question text. It would make the question more comprehensive.

Comment: @Apoorv rule 2.9 added. :)